# How to expand only bash a specific $variable at any certain point

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

How to expand only bash $variable at any certain point of anything (time, condition, etc) ?
as this works :

```
 i=1
  u="sum = $i + \$o"
  o=two; n=$(eval echo $u)
```

to equalize to `n='sum = 1 + two'`

the truth,  `$(eval echo $)`  won't work for complex long expression
The real case the u above is some find arguments as, e.g., the output of set -x:

```
C='( -ipath /home/olive/build/CMakeFiles/* (  ( -type d ( -regex .*\s.* -printf '\''%p/'\''\n -o -printf %p/\n ) -o ( -regex .*\s.* -printf '\''%p'\''\n -o -printf %p\n ) ) ) -o -ipath /home/olive/build/CMakeFiles -type f ( -regex .*\s.* -printf '\''%p'\''\n -o -printf %p\n ) -o -iregex .{17}/.+/CMakeFiles$RP ( -type d ( -regex .*\s.* -printf '\''%p/'\''\n -o -printf %p/\n ) -o ( -regex .*\s.* -printf '\''%p'\''\n -o -printf %p\n ) ) )'
```

So $RP there is big need to be expanded after once expansion (like $o on sample)

So how to expand only a bash variable at any certain arbitrary point without touch any else expression in which the var. sit

Comment: Use an array instead, like `C=(foo '' bar); C[1]=x; find "${C[@]}"; C[1]=y; find "${C[@]}"`. There is no reason to use eval and a scalar variable here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking something like the below shows (indirect variable lookup) - then use `${!variablename}` to do an indirect lookup of the variable whose name is in `variablename`.

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

v1=23
v2=v1

echo "Lookup ${!v2} should be 23"

v1=49

echo "Lookup ${!v2} should be 49"
```

Gives this output ..

```
Lookup 23 should be 23
Lookup 49 should be 49
```